# The difference between "Zeuge'' and ''Zeitzeuge''?

Tags: meaning

And what does "Zeugen der Zeitzeugen" mean?

Comment: Could you please edit your post and clarify, why looking up those words in a dictionary didn't help you to grasp the meaning?

Comment: Is there a context or a complete sentence?

Answer (score 4):

- Zeuge = witness
- Zeitzeuge = contemporary witness

### Zeuge

If you watch a crime, and afterwards police officers ask you to describe what you have seen, then you are a *Zeuge.*

If good friends of you marry, they might ask you to sign a document during the wedding to attest that they really did marry. This also makes you a *Zeuge* (*Trauzeuge* in this special case, *Trauung* = marriage)

So, a *Zeuge* is a person that perceives (sees, hears etc.) something and can later confirm this perception, when appropriate even under oath.

---

### Zeitzeuge

This is a person who lived in a specific era or when an important historic event happened and who can tell other people who didn't live in this time, how it was to be in involved in this event or era.

Very often you hear this term for people who survived while their relatives where killed by the nazis in WW II. But you are also a *Zeitzeuge* if you are witness of another era or some other historic event.

An example:
At the moment there are some student apprentices working at the university where I work (the help us to do some researches), and they all were born after the year 2000 (they are between 15 and 18 years old). They have no idea how it was when people didn't have smartphones and internet. But my colleagues and I lived in times where we managed to live without this kind of infrastructure, and so we are *Zeitzeugen* of the pre-internet era.

Answer (score 2):

A **Zeitzeuge** is mainly an old person reporting from the time of their youth. A *contemporary witness*. In Germany, this meant someone reports about life in Nazi Germany and concentration camps. But as those people almost all died of old age by now, the current *Zeitzeugen* are those reporting about life in early East and West Germany, about the cold war.

There is another use of this word *Zeitzeugen* which applies to photos of a certain time in history. For example, a photo of the Brandenburg Gate with the Berlin Wall in front of it qualifies as a *Zeitzeuge* as well.

---

*Zeuge der Zeitzeugen* in contrary is *Chinese whispers*.

It's an organisation who is confronted with the fact almost all the *Zeitzeugen* of the Nazi terror died of old age. They can't tell their stories any more, so people who heard their stories should trade it on.

Comment: Weder muss ein Zeitzeuge alt sein, noch von seiner Jugend berichten. Außerdem ist das Wort im Deutschen nicht auf deutsche Zeitgeschichte beschränkt, im Speziellen nicht auf die Nazizeit und die deutsche Teilung. Ein Inder der als Erwachsener etwas von öffentlichem Interesse erlebt hat, wird im Deutschen genauso als Zeitzeuge bezeichnet.

Comment: *bezeugen* is analog to *convict*, *persuade*, still visible in *Überzeugung*, perhaps from religious context. That is, an involved party would be a *Zeitzeuge* of the momentary spirit, which is a different sense than for a mere observer. However, a conscious differentiation of that sense is hardly observed, as the stem *zeug-* is rather wide, as *Zeugnis, Erzeugnis, Zeug*, *Zucht*, En *token, teach, teacher, tech(?), toy* diverge. Yet, for *whitness* cp  *Mitwisser* - an involved party indeed. It's just that in absence of evidence, prosecuters will produce a convict out of thin air if needed.

Comment: I don't really think this answers the question. What is the difference to Zeuge? Furthermore I agree with user unknown.

Comment: Ich denke hingegen, das Wort *Zeuge* steht bereits im Wörterbuch. Weiterhin habe ich sehr deutlich (*mainly*, *in Germany*) hingeschrieben, unter welchen Einschränkungen das von mir Geschriebene gilt. Anhand dieses Beispiels kann man die anderen Fälle dann extrapolieren. Im speziell gefragten Beispiel ging es um *Zeuge der Zeitzeugen*, was für mich heißt, dass es dem Frager mitnichten um indische Geschichte geht.